# How to copy text written with @ in excel

Tags: excel, web, excel-formula, copy, paste

I have a formula for this -

```
  =CONCATENATE(IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B4,FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(B4,"@","~~",1)),LEN(B4))," ",REPT(" ",100),1),100)),""),",",IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B4,FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(B4,"@","~~",2)),LEN(B4))," ",REPT(" ",100),1),100)),""),",",IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B4,FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(B4,"@","~~",3)),LEN(B4))," ",REPT(" ",100),1),100)),""))
```

But problem with this is that it only give results up to 3 words from a line with @ . For example if i have line - The @Sun is @beautiful and @only @star in the @solar system . This will give result - @sun @beautiful @only . But i want a formula so that i can extract all words with "@" from that line or paragraph . Please tell me if this is possible in excel or anyhow it is possible with another tool or any website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `XPATH`'s function [`starts-with()`](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide6/xpath-starts-with) through `FILTERXML`, available from Excel 2013 but not Excel Online nor Excel for Mac:

[image]

Formula in `B1` using Excel O365:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., '@')]")
```

If you don't have Excel O365, you may need to throw in an `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., '@')]"),ROW())`
```

And offcourse, if you need all values concatenated through, for example a comma, you could use `TEXTJOIN`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., '@')]"))
```

---

A formula I checked for Excel Online would be longer but you may try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(MID(A1,IF(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)="@",SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),""),FIND(" ",A1&" ",IF(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)="@",SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),""))-IF(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)="@",SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),"")),""))
```

Comment: Can this be used in Microsoft Android app too ?

Comment: I want it to copy following list of a Twitter account . Tell me if you know any other way to do this task . Many tools are available but they are paid .

Comment: Please answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607848/how-to-copy-following-list-of-a-twitter-account

Comment: Right then I have misunderstood you second question and I don't know how to pull that information I'm sorry

Comment: This is excel related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612589/how-to-slip-text-into-new-paragraph-after-every-n-words