# How to slip text into new paragraph after every n words

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working in excel . Say i have a text --> one two three four five six seven eight nine ten  . Now if i want to change paragraph line after every 3 words  -

One two three

Four five six

Seven eight nine

Ten

Tell me if this is possible in excel . Or if there is another way to do it

Comment: Probably be easier to do it in VBA. Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's *'OK'* to do in Excel I'd guess. But you'd need `CONCAT` which comes with ExcelO365 or Excel 2019. And it would be handy to have ExcelO365 alltogether to use `SEQUENCE`. For example:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=CONCAT(IF(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)=" ",IF(MOD(LEN(LEFT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)))," ","")),3)=0,CHAR(10),MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)),MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))
```

At the centre of the formula is `MOD` which tells if the placement of any space is in the table of three. If so, we replace it with a newline before we concatenate the string back together.